# A tiny command-line program that prints a sum of numbers

Tags: console, rust

Here's my first Rust program that I could actually use for something:

```
use std::io;
use std::process;

fn main() {
    let mut sum = 0;
    loop {
        let mut number_str = String::new();
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut number_str) {
            Ok(n) => { if n == 0 {break} },
            Err(e) => { println!("ERROR: got '{}' when reading a line", e) }
        }
        match number_str.trim().parse::<i32>() {
            Ok(n) => { sum += n }
            Err(n) => {
                println!("ERROR: Entered something that is not a number: '{}'",
                    number_str.trim_right());
                process::exit(1)
            },
        }
    }
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

Did I violate any style rules? Is there anything else I should add/change/improve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have a compiler warning. One of the points of using a statically typed language is to have the compiler watching your back. If you ignore what the compiler says, you lose out.

   ```
   warning: unused variable: `n`, #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
     --> main.rs:14:17
      |
   14 |             Err(n) => {
      |                 ^
   ```
2. If you don't care about the value, use an underscore (`_`).
3. Learn and love [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt).

   1. There are no braces on one-line match arms.
   2. Always use trailing commas on multiple line items.
   3. Use spaces inside braces (`{ break }`).
4. If the current code encounters an error while reading input, it continues processing. That seems unintuitive.
5. The current code uses `trim` when parsing, but only `trim_right` when showing the error to the user. This seems like a way of confusing the user when the error occurs.
6. It's potentially inefficient to reallocate the string in each iteration. Moving it outside the loop would mean you are responsible for clearing it each iteration. Failing to clear it would be a bug and potential security hole.
7. However, the code to process each line is [already implemented for you](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines).
8. There's duplicate error handling code. I'd extract a method to be able to use `Result`. I love using `quick_error` to construct error enumerations. This lets you use `try!` or `?`.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::process;

use quick_error::ResultExt;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum Error {
        Io(err: io::Error) {
            from()
            description("unable to read line")
            display("Unable to read line: {}", err)
            cause(err)
        }
        Parse(err: std::num::ParseIntError, num: String) {
            description("unable to parse number")
            display("Unable to parse '{}': {}", num, err)
            cause(err)
            context(num: &'a str, err: std::num::ParseIntError) -> (err, num.into())
        }
    }
}

fn inner_main() -> Result<i32, Error> {
    let mut sum = 0;

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        let line = line?;
        let line = line.trim();
        sum += line.parse().context(line)?;
    }

    Ok(sum)
}

fn main() {
    match inner_main() {
        Ok(sum) => println!("{}", sum),
        Err(e) => {
            println!("ERROR: {}", e);
            process::exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this  quick_error thing is nice! You separated error handling from the general logic in a great way, thanks.

Comment: @d33tah I think that separation is very valuable, especially in Rust, where many more classes of errors are front-and-center. Not many other languages expose the potential for reading from stdin to fail, but it can certainly happen!

Comment: I re-read the code, experimented with it and tried to actually understand it and my brain freezes at `context(num: &'a str, err: std::num::ParseIntError) -> (err, num.into())`. I guess I'll need to learn a bit to be able to use libraries like that. Could this code be as clean without quick_error?

Comment: @d33tah macros can appear to be some of the more magical aspects of Rust, but usually they are "just" ways of expressing a shorthand for a common pattern. In this case, that bit of macro is likely creating a `From` implementation that converts into the `Error` type. I'd certainly encourage you to implement `Error` by hand to start with. Just... delete `quick_error! { ... }` and the call to `.context(...)` and see if you can reimplement the same functionality. You'll learn about `std::error::Error` and `From` / `Into` and maybe some more.

Comment: Once you have done that, then you will have an appreciation for the shorthand that the macro gives you, or maybe you'll want to look at other libraries that provide similar convenience...